# Re-asigning a value to a variable empties memory?

Tags: python, object, memory-management

I have a list that has an undeterminate number of object instances. Some of these objects also contain objects of their own:

```
class foo:
    var1 = 0
    var2 = [objc()]

list = [foo(), foo(), foo(), foo()]
```

If this list is emptied by re-defining it - does this operation removes all the objects in the list (including the objects that are inside of these from memory)?

```
list = []
```

Will `del` work?

```
del list
```

And the method `pop`?

```
for e in list:
    list.pop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer - it depends.

Your first example is not a good one as `foo.var2` is a class attribute, ie it is created at byte code compile time. You access it by `foo.var2`.

For a `my_foo = foo()`, its `my_foo.var2` *is the same object* as `foo.var2` and on every other instance of the `foo` class plus `foo.var2` itself *unless* it has been overridden by an object variable of the same name, ie `my_foo.var2 = []`.

Neither will de-allocate a class attribute as it is created at compile time, or when the class is imported in python.

So the answer for your specific question of how to deallocate a class attribute is you can't. As long as there is a reference to it, which there always will be if the class was imported, the GC will never deallocate it.

Also, changing class attribute members in one instance of the class, like with a `.pop`, will change it for all other instances as well as the class attribute itself as they're the same object.

In general mutable objects as class attributes are a bad idea for the above reasons.

Use instance variables for mutable things, class attributes for static things - that's what they are for. De-referencing will work as expected then.

```
class Foo(object):
    st1 = "something static"

    def __init__(self):
        self.var1 = 0
        self.var2 = [objc()]

foo = Foo()
# De-allocates objc() if there are no other references to it
foo.var2 = []
```